# Filtering issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jquery with the following intention.

I select the divs having an z-index inferior to 100 and then I surround the img element inside of those divs with a class blue div.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(".contentHolderUnit").each(function()
{
    if($(this).css("z-index") <  100)
    {

        $("img").wrap('<div class="blue" />');
        //$("img").css({"opacity": "0.75"});
    }
});

});
```

What really happens is that **every** img element on the page is selected, and for some reason is surrounded by **3** class blue divs.

one of the targeted divs:
( z-index is 100 and wasn't filtered out, and 3 blue class divs)

```
<div class="contentHolderUnit" rel="0" id="contentHolderUnit_0" style="display: block; height: 385px; width: 520px; left: 240px; top: 15px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1;"> <div class="blue"><div class="blue"><div class="blue"><img src="any" style="height: 385px; width: 520px; opacity: 0.75; display: inline-block;"></div></div></div><div class="car">
Example Title
</div></div>
```

Comment: `$("img")` will wrap all `img` tags. Should be `$(this)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selecting all images in the DOM on each iteration, not just the ones inside the elements with the z-index etc. I'd just use a filter, and find() instead of a loop :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".contentHolderUnit").filter(function(i, el) {
        return el.style.zIndex < 100;
    }).find('img').wrap('<div class="blue" />')
                  .css({opacity: 0.75});
});
```

Comment: Lifesaver answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Because your `$("img")` selector is selecting every image on the page. You need to select inside the parent like this:

```
$(this).children("img");
```